# How do I make a part of a graphic transparent in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

With Illustrator, how do I make the skull transparent? Every element is on a separate layer (including the set of teeth) and I'm trying to have only what's in teal cut all the way through the logo.

Using pathfinder & minus just removes the skull entirely & Shape Builder + alt just removes it too.

Help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Or use a knockout group.

Comment: Probably going to need more info... Shape Builder/Pathfinder should work. Show a screenshot of the layers and appearance panels with things selected. You can try putting it all on a single layer. Although that shouldn't matter for Shape Builder/Pathfinder.. maybe things have changed in recent versions.

Comment: Added a screenshot of my layers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will destroy the layer structure and place everything on one layer. Since the desire is a single compound shape, that would only encompass a single layer anyway. This combines all the separate pieces and results in a **single** compound shape with a "hole" for the skull.

<sup>Work on a *copy* of the artwork if the desire is to retain the current layer structure (and separate artwork pieces).</sup>

- Select all
- Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` ( *if it's available* )
- Choose `Object > Expand`
- Hit the `Merge` button on the **Pathfinder Panel** (it'll now be 1 layer)
- Select and delete the light teal shapes.

You're left with a hole where the teal is currently.

---

I'd *guess* you were experiencing pathfinder/Shape Builder issue due the stacking of objects. With that stacking it would take more "alt-clicks" than "click-drags" with Shape Builder. And you'd need to *specifically* select *only* a couple shapes for Pathfinder to work properly.

Chances are you could select *only* the "Skull", "Teeth", and "Hood" then <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-**click** the "Skull" and the "Teeth" with the **Shape Builder** Tool, and that may be enough.

Comment: Worked! Thank you!